# Firebase Client access to your Realtime Database has expired

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

[image: Email from Firebase about expied database]

So I got this mail from Firebase saying all client requests to my Realtime Database instance have been denied and will continue to be denied until security rules are updated...

[image: won't accept new rule that I've edited]

This is me trying to update the security rules but i don't really understand what exactly I'm supposed to write here. I just want to stop receiving these emails from Firebase and ofcourse, update my security rules.
Somebody just help me paste the command that i should use here. I don't think i understand the code that they need.
Kindly paste the right code in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: The screenshot that you shared of the Firebase rules are not of realtime database, it's of firestore.

Comment: @Kundan i just copy-pasted that code from some StackOverflow conversation as well. It didn't work. I was just trying different things. The code that i found there is much different.